# Find the cardinality of $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R \times \mathbb Q : x^2 - y = 0 \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Find the cardinality of $A =\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R \times \mathbb Q :
> > x^2 - y = 0 \}\}$

This question may seem trivially easy but I have just started learning about cardinality and still find some things confusing. 
My attempt: First of all, I rewrote the definition of the set in a simpler way, adding $y$ to both sides and making necessary assumptions
$$A =\{(x,x^2) : x \in \mathbb R \land x^2 \in \mathbb Q \} = \{(x,x^2) : x\in \mathbb Q \} \cup \{(\pm\sqrt q , q):q \in \mathbb Q \}$$
Now, the cardinality of both of these sets is $\aleph_0$, thus the cardinality of the set in question is $\aleph_o$ 
Is my solution correct? I not, where have I made a mistake?

Comment: You made a mistake rewriting $A$. For example $(2, \sqrt{2}) \in A$ but it's not in your set.

Comment: $A = \{(\pm \sqrt{y},y):y \in Q \land y \ge 0\}$.

Comment: @StefanMesken 
Why $(2, \sqrt 2) \in A$? $2^2 \ne \sqrt 2$

Comment: I messed up the order. I meant $(\sqrt{2},2) \in A$.

Comment: Sorry, but I still can't see what's the problem with my definition of the set. $x^2 - y = 0 \iff y = x^2$

Comment: Why you say that $\sqrt{q}\in A$?

Comment: The ordered pair is backwards.  You want $A =\{(x^2,x) : x^2 \in \mathbb R \land x \in \mathbb Q \}$  You want the unsquared one to be rational.  Then Eric Towers' argument is spot on.

Answer (score 2):

Yes $x^2 = y$, but since $\mathbb{R}$ contains all the square roots of elements of $\mathbb{Q}$, perhaps $\{(\pm\sqrt{y}, y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q} \}$ would be a bit simpler.  Then this set has one element per element of $\mathbb{Q}$...

Comment: You should put a $\pm$ before $\sqrt y$ as the negative ones are in the set as well.

Comment: Thanks, this solution is in fact simpler. But what is the problem in mine?

Comment: @RossMillikan : What?  Not everyone uses the multivalued function $\sqrt{\cdot}$?  (Thanks.  Fixed.)

Comment: @Aemilius : While your equality of $A$ with a union of two sets is valid, it twice includes every element (the two sets on the right are identical).  This isn't fatal, but it is a longer/harder story to tell and to explain clearly.

Comment: They are not identiclal. For example, the first set does not include $(\sqrt 2, 2)$

Comment: @Aemilius : Even worse...  Your story has (not actually) misled at least one reader...

Answer (score 1):

The  cardinality of the set  $$A =\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R \times \mathbb Q :
> x^2 - y = 0 \}\}$$ is $\aleph_0$.

Note that for any  positive rational number $y$, you get two elements of $A$ , namely,( $\sqrt y ,y)$ and $ (-\sqrt y , y)$.

Therefore your set is infinitely countable.

You also have $(0,0)$ in your set which does not change the cardinality.

Thus the  cardinality of $A$ is  $\aleph_0$.